# Problems loading helper class in own Typo3 Formhandler Finisher

Tags: namespaces, typo3, autoloader

I try to include an external php-based library 'Foobar' in my own formhandler finisher.

The library is made in current programming methods like OOP and namespaces. Each class is located in it's own file... there are over 30 files in 3 folders. It even provides a "composer.json"-file...

Basically the finisher works, however, I can't access the library.

I put them all under myext/Classes/Foobar (I also tried myext/Classes/Finisher/Foobar) in the hope that Typo3's autoloader / class loader finds them but no luck. Even putting the classes in an "ext_autoloader.php"-file didn't help - they cannot be found neither by using the new-directive nor the makeinstance-function.

I added a db-record in TCA and gave it an vendor-name... nope. And if I try to put my finisher in the same namespace the form isn't even displayed.

In the T3-repository I found the extension "formhandler_subscription" which loads helper classes in his extra finishers via "ext_autoloader.php"... however, their helperclasses don't use namespaces and they are all in one single file...

So, can someone help me please? What should I do that Typo3 loads the external library and makes it available to my finisher?

thanks in advance!

edit: I'm using Typo3 6.2.12!

Comment: How are you instanciating your class? `new`, `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()`, dependency injection? In one of my custom finishers it worked fine by using `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` to create an instance of `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager`, and the use that instance to get an instance of my service. Using the object manager makes sure that dependency injection is done for my own service class.

Comment: Thank you so far. Could you please describe your folder structure where you put in your classes?

Comment: I put the finisher in some folder in the fileadmin, besides the other stuff from that form, and then included it using formhandlers own include mechanism: http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/blog/howtos/how-to-use-your-own-component/